# Laravel: How do I insert a multidimensional array in the controller

Tags: laravel, multidimensional-array, foreach, controller, insert

**Table:**

this is the table being used from the SQL database (id is auto incremented)

[image: 1]

**Array:**

then output below is from the console of the browser after adding in: `dd($replies);`

[image: 2]

The screenshot below shows the input of the ui, which is the same data registered in the array in the screenshot above
[image: 3]

**Entities:**

The function below is being used to create/insert the data

```
public function create($payload_reply)
{
    return rescue(function() use($payload_reply){
        return self::insert($payload_reply);
    });
}
```

**Controller:**

My issue is with my code below

```
if($result){

$replies = $request->get('reply');
dd($replies);

$payload_reply = [];
foreach($replies as $reply){
    $payload_reply = [...$payload_reply, [
        'id' => $request->get('group_id'),
        'message_id' => $request->get('message_id'),
        'parent_id' => $request->get('message_id'),
        'reply' => $request->get('reply'),
        'reply_type' => $request->get('reply_type'),
        'reply_description' => $request->get('reply_description')
    ]];
}
$result = $this->bbrMessageTemplate->create($payload_reply);
}
```

This code does not insert the array in my table. I tried a for each loop in order for each data to be inserted one at a time until all have been inserted. What did I do wrong? I am not sure if it is the array or the for each.

Any help would be appreciated.

Clarifications: my variable `$result` works fine, so it leads to this if statement which is my main issue.

Comment: Can you add your whole `controller` function ? or controller itself better.

Comment: There might be an exception thrown but you're catching it with rescue. Try not wrapping the insert logic in rescue and see what the exception is.

Comment: Can you add a ```dd($payload_reply)``` after foreach array assingments, and include the $payload_reply result on your question ?